# Scala recursion explanation from Scala book

Tags: scala, recursion

I was going through scala book by Martin Odersky. In chapter10(Composition and Inheritance), in this code:

```
def spiral(nEdges: Int, direction: Int): Element = {
    if (nEdges == 1) {
      elem("+")
    }
    else {
      println(s"nEdgesInside1=$nEdges")

      val sp = spiral(nEdges - 1, (direction + 3) % 4)

      def verticalBar = elem('|', 1, sp.height)

      def horizontalBar = elem('-', sp.width, 1)

      println(s"nEdgesInside2=$nEdges")

      if (direction == 0)
        (corner beside horizontalBar) above (sp beside space)
      else if (direction == 1)
        (sp above space) beside (corner above verticalBar)
      else if (direction == 2)
        (space beside sp) above (horizontalBar beside corner)
      else
        (verticalBar above corner) beside (space above sp)
    }
  }
```

I am unable to understand how code flows beyond the line:

```
val sp = spiral(nEdges - 1, (direction + 3) % 4)
```

Accoording to my understanding, `nEdges` is getting decremented in every iteration `spiral` function is called and once it reaches 1(i.e termination condition) it creates object via `elem` function.

When I test this code and print the values of `nEdges`, it gets decremented till the line above call of `spiral` function and after that line it starts to increment. Could anyone explain me how this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically how recursion works. `edges` gets decremented until it reaches 1, and while doing that it keeps calling `spiral` which generates more stack frames, each with it's own value of `nEdges` and `direction`. Once we hit 1, the call stack starts to unwind, older stack frames get destroyed, which means lesser values of these two fields get discarded in place of values higher up the stackframe, where they have a higher value.

For example, take this image of a recursive factorial calculation:

[image: Factorial recursive]

(© Chen Yu. Jade - http://jade-cheng.com/hpu/2012-spring/csci-2912/recursion/)

Imagine that `n` stands for `nEdges`, you see that it's decremented with each method call, and when `n = 0`, we start unwinding and go higher and higher up the stack where `n` had a higher value.